# Aws ec2 - how to connect mongodb remote server?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, amazon-ec2

I have MongoDB running on my Ubuntu server in Amazon EC2. Since there’s no simple all-in-one tutorial out there explaining how to set up remote server properly.

**I have create BD user and password.**

[image]

#### When I'm trying to connect remotely to my local-server it's says ReferenceError: db is not defined.

[image]

** I'm trying to use **

```
const DB_URI = `mongodb://${cfg.mongoDbUser}:${cfg.mongoDbPass}@${cfg.mongoDbHost}:${cfg.mongoDbPort}/${cfg.mongoDbName}`
```

**Hope expert will suggest me**

*Regards*

**As Md Habibullah**

Comment: "db is not defined" --- means you're using variable that was not declared yet. It has nothing to do with ec2 in particular.

Comment: The top one appears to be the standalone Mongo client, and the second one appears to be code from your application.

Comment: I have declare variable on my env file

Comment: "I have declare variable on my env file" --- it's not how it works. Variables might only be declared in your JS code.

Comment: Do you have any connection restrictions on your machine? does the connection succeed? maybe you should add a larger code snippet including all relevant parts.

Comment: I don't know about connection restrictions on my machine. @TomSlabbaert
How can I check it?

Comment: Can you log into your ec2 instance without a private key? or a user/password?

Comment: No, I can't log.

Comment: @Thank you all. I solved this problem.

Comment: @AsMdHabibullah If you managed to solve the problem, please either add an Answer so that other people may benefit, or feel free to Delete this question if it will not be of benefit to people in future.

Comment: Sure — John, I will